# Cordova App and Google Analytics

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

I'm working at a Cordova App intended for iOS and Android devices and for mobile site. I need to send data to Google Analytics (both pageviews and events).

I have an important design requirement: the codebase must be the same for the three different platforms; no ad-hoc code for iOS or Android.

Why should I include GA SDK in the apps? The pageviews and event tracking code I will write for the mobile site won't work for the apps? Will I lose some informations (app version, app os, etc.)?

Thanks in advance
Diego

Answer (score 0):

The last I read on this subject was:

Google Analytics won't work if its being used from a file:/// url. This is how it is used in Cordova.

This explains that for the Cordova app in particular you will need the Google analytics SDK and a plugin to work with it.

I haven't researched the subject for a while and this may have changed but I doubt it. Similar to AdSense and AdMob, Google likes to know exactly where traffic is coming from.

Comment: I simply implemented the GA web tracking inside my JS/HTML code and it seems all informations I need are available inside GA: devices, OS versions, etc. I followed this guide to send screenview (no pageview) and event:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens.

Comment: @diego, when you created the new property so you could get the tracking ID in Google Analytics, did you choose "Website" or "Mobile App".  When I click on Website it wants me to submit a URL, when I click on Mobile App it wants me to use the Firebase SDK.  Not sure which one to go with